# Create dual-stack socket on all loopback interfaces on Windows

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, ipv6

I an trying to create a [dual-stack socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513665(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows 7, for listening on both 127.0.0.1 and ::1 interfaces. I do not want to listen on all interfaces (0.0.0.0), just the loopback ones.

For dual-stack sockets, I have found that I need to disable the [IPV6_V6ONLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms738574(v=vs.85).aspx) option. I created a sample app which does just that (see below). When the app is running, `netstat -an` gives me the following output:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:27015          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    [::1]:27015            [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

When connecting with putty on ::1, everything works. However, when I try to connect to 127.0.0.1, I get "Connection refused".

When creating a socket on the "::" IPv6 address with the V6ONLY option disabled, I am able to connect on both IPv4 and IPv6, as expected.

So, how do I create a socket that listens on both IPv4 and IPv6 loopback interfaces?

Sample app I used for testing, adapted from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int __cdecl main(void) 
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    //hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo("localhost", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Disable V6ONLY, so we get IPv4 
    int disable = 0;
    iResult = setsockopt(ListenSocket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, (char*)&disable, sizeof(disable));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("setsockopt failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // No longer need server socket
    closesocket(ListenSocket);

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

        // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0 );
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        else  {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

    } while (iResult > 0);

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create two sockets for this case. Creating a separate socket for each protocol/address is the normal way of doing this. There is the `::/0` with `V6ONLY=0` shortcut if you want to listen on any address on both IPv4 and IPv6, but for anything other than that you'll have to create multiple sockets.

Technically you can bind a server socket with `V6ONLY=0` to an IPv4 mapped address, but there is not really any point in doing so. `IN6ADDR_ANY` is the only useful case. It makes the socket listen on any IPv6 address, including IPv4 mapped addresses (which are really IPv4 addresses in disguise).

Once you bind a socket to an address that binding acts like a filter, and only packets destined for that address will be received on the socket. And `::1` is a different address than `::ffff:127.0.0.1`, so a socket bound to one will not receive messages for the other. You seem to assume that there is some implicit mapping between IPv4 and IPv6, but there isn't except for the IPv4 mapped addresses. Each address is unique.

Once you bind a socket it will only work for one address. For other addresses you'd need extra sockets, so in those cases you might as well just create a real IPv4 socket.

Comment: The whole point of creating a dual-stack socket is so that you DON'T have to create separate sockets on the same port.

Comment: Dual-stack sockets are an exception, usable in one use case. Single-stack sockets are normal and what you need in all other cases. For client code you can use method 2 from Remy's answer. For server code you need to listen on multiple sockets and use e.g. `select` to handle events on those multiple sockets.

Comment: The OP's question is in relation to that one use case in server code.  A server can bind a dual-stack socket to both IPv4 and IPv6 on a single port. A client should use `AF_UNSPEC` with `getaddrinfo()` and then loop through the entire list until `connect()` successfully connects to one of the addresses, since it doesn't know which protocol/address the server may actually be reachable with.

Comment: A server can only listen on a dual stack socket if listening to the unspecified IPv6 address (so all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses). The OP asks how to use a dual stack socket when listening to specific addresses, and the answer is: you can't. It might not be what they want to hear, but that's the answer...

Comment: I was able to replicate the OP's issue. I created a dual-stack IPv6 socket bound to `::1` (IN6ADDR_LOOPBACK), and I see it listening on both `0.0.0.0` (INADDR_ANY) and `::1`, but putty can only connect to `::1` and not `127.0.0.1`. When I bind to `::` (IN6ADDR_ANY) instead, I see it listening on both `0.0.0.0` and `::`, but putty can still only connect to `::1` and not `127.0.0.1`. When I bind it to an actual adapter IPv6 address, I see it only listening on that IP, and putty can connect to that IP, but not to the IPv4 address of the same adapter.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to get putty to connect to `127.0.0.1` when the server is bound to `::`, but not to `::1`.

Comment: Correct. That is as designed: `V6ONLY=0` only works with `IN6ADDR_ANY`

Comment: @Steffann I could not find any documentation hinting that this is the design rather than a bug. Do you have any such references?

Comment: I'll expand my answer to make the situation more clear

Comment: @SanderSteffann Thanks, this makes it totally clear and obvious now: "IN6ADDR_ANY makes the socket listen on any IPv6 address, including IPv4 mapped addresses".

Answer (score 1):

> When creating a socket on the "::" IPv6 address with the V6ONLY option disabled, I am able to connect on both IPv4 and IPv6, as expected.

That is exactly what you should be doing, and how it is designed to work.

A dual-stack socket must be created as an `AF_INET6` socket, which means you have to `bind()` it to an IPv6 address. But your code is not ensuring that. `IPV6_V6ONLY` only works with an `AF_INET6` socket, not an `AF_INET` socket.

When you call `getaddrinfo()`, you are using `AF_UNSPEC`, which gives `getaddrinfo()` permission to return of list of *either* `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` address(es), or even *both* at the same time.  You are not taking that into account, or the order in which `getaddrinfo()` reports them.  you are creating a socket for whatever address is first in the list.  There may be more than one address reported.

So, either:

1. set `hints.ai_family` to `AF_INET6` so `getaddrinfo()` can only report `AF_INET6` addresses, and then you can disable `IPV6_V6ONLY` on any `AF_INET6` socket you create.
2. set `hints.ai_family` to `AF_UNSPEC`, then create a separate socket for every address that `getaddrinfo()` actually reports (which you should be doing anyway), so you can create both `AF_INET` and `AF_INET6` sockets at the same time.  In this case, you should not disable `IPV6_V6ONLY` on any `AF_INET6` socket you create if a corresponding `AF_INET` address was also reported.

---

**Update**: so, apparently an IPv4 client can connect to `127.0.0.1` (aka `INADDR_LOOPBACK`) on an IPv6 dual-stack listening socket only if the listening socket is bound to `::` (aka `IN6ADDR_ANY`), which will also listen on `0.0.0.0` (aka `INADDR_ANY`).  Binding to `::1` (aka `IN6ADDR_LOOPBACK`) will listen on `0.0.0.0` (instead of `127.0.0.1`), but an IPv4 client cannot actually connect to `127.0.0.1`.  So, if you want to bind an IPv6 listening socket to `::1` and still allow IPv4 clients to connect to `127.0.0.1`, you will have to create a separate IPv4 listening socket bound to `127.0.0.1`.  So that goes back to #2 above.

When binding a dual-stack listening socket to `::1`, one would think it would listen on `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`.  Seems like a bug to me.